# How can I select one of each category with a Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
author|string
abc|hi
abc|yo
def|whats
ghi|up
ghi|dog
```

how can I select only one row per author? I'm at a loss.
I want to do something like this:

`df.loc[unique authors].sample(n=1000)`

and get something like this:

```
author|string
abc|hi
def|whats
ghi|up
```

I was thinking of converting the author column to categories, but I don't know where to go from there.

I could just do something like this but it seems stupid.

```
author_list = df['author'].unique().tolist()
indexes = []
for author in author_list:
  indexes.append(df.loc[df['author'] == author].iloc[0].index)
df.iloc[indexes].sample(n=1000)
```

Comment: Do you not care about what "string" you get against each author?

Comment: Do you have two columns, or one, where the one is a string literally separated by `|`?

Comment: No I'm happy with any string as long as author is unique :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
out = df.drop_duplicates('author')
```

Comment: Brilliant! So I can do this?

df_sample = df.iloc[df.drop_duplicates('author').index].sample(n=1000)

Comment: @yes yes as your name

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

```
# sample 1 'string' of each 'author' group 
res = df.groupby('author').sample(1)
```

Output

```
>>> for _ in range(3):
...     print(df.groupby('author').sample(1), '\n')


  author string
0    abc     hi
2    def  whats
3    ghi     up 

  author string
0    abc     hi
2    def  whats
3    ghi     up 

  author string
1    abc     yo
2    def  whats
4    ghi    dog
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'author': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi'],
    'string': ['hi', 'yo', 'whats', 'up', 'dog']
})
```

---

Note that the random sampling is done for each column of each group separately. Since you are just sampling one column, it doesn't matter. But if your DataFrame has multiple columns and you want to sample a random row as a whole from each group use

```
res = df.groupby('author', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=1)
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: @yes No problem, I'm glad to help ;)  I've edited the answer with a side note.

Comment: Actually it seems to be incredibly slow, maybe the other solution posted by @BENY is better?

df_sample = df.iloc[df.drop_duplicates('author').index].sample(n=1000)

edit: oh I didn't see your side note. I wonder which solution is fastest.

Comment: @yes BENY solution doesn't do random sampling. You will get always the same solution (the rows where each author appears for the first time in your DataFrame). It doesn't seem that you want that according to the description of the problem.

Comment: Aha, didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: @yes also define 'incredibly slow'? It's vectorized, in the example case it's the fastest solution. But if you have more columns, using `groupby` + `apply` is not ideal. If you want a faster solution, sample the index column only and use the result to index your DataFrame similarly as you are doing in your attempt.

Comment: I see, thank you. It seemed to take several minutes to execute in comparison with the df.drop_duplicates method that took a second or so.